# "the type or namespace name 'TestSuite' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am facing an error "the type or namespace name 'TestSuite' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" 
Can anyone let me know whats the problems. I am using VS2010 ultimate and with following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

[Suite]
public static TestSuite Suite
{
    //Doing test suites
}
```

Comment: Clue is in the error. Whatever the `TestSuite` namespace relates to, you don't have a reference to that assembly. What does it relate to?

Comment: Can u tell me what reference should be added? i have added nunit.framework 
Webdriver ,webdriversupport

Comment: What version of NUnit are you using? Also post a screenshot of your 'References' window.

Comment: i am using NUnit-2.6.2.msi

Comment: I would add a reference to NUnit.Core as well.

Comment: microsoft.csharp , nunit.framework, system, system.core, system.Data, System.Data.DataSetExtensions, System.Drawings, System.Xml,System.XML.linq, webdriver, webdriver.support

Comment: Nunit.Core reference could not be found in this version of Nunit, is there any alternate of this?? :(

Comment: or from where i can found this?

Comment: Should exist under the folder where you installed NUnit too...for me this is in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.1\bin\lib`, I can see `nunit.core.dll` ...it may not be the Core dll that you need, but looking at NUnit's source, the `TestSuite` class is in that assembly.

Comment: Having the same issue, was this solved?

Comment: yeah it was solved.. Thanks Arran. and sorry for late response.